# Login With Twitter and fatch user profile from twitter in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have tried various third party tools like `FHSTwitterEngine` and `STTWitter` to get user's profile like **image, firstname, email, address, dob** etc. I have been doing google since last 6 hours. but I am not able to get user's profile from twitter. I have referred lot of links on stackoverflow but I am not able to get result which I want.

Anyone can help me in this issue?

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get [variety of information](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users) about a user through the [GET users/show](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show) API endpoint, but it doesn't include the email address.